# Modifying `Request.Path` via middleware in an ASP.NET Core Web API project does not change the controller/action used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, middleware, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a small sandbox application based on the ASP.NET Core Web API template where I am attempting to modify the controller/action to be used based on a custom header and to facilitate this I am replacing the value of the `context.Request.Path` property.

However, despite confirming via debugging that the middleware is running, that the conditions for replacement are being met and that the value of `Request.Path` have been changed, the application is still using the controller and action that would have been used should the path have remain unchanged.

The configuration of the application is:

```
using Sandbox.Middleware;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseMiddleware<ModifyControllerMiddleware>();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And the middleware itself:

```
namespace Sandbox.Middleware
{
    public class ModifyControllerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ModifyControllerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            switch (context.Request.Headers["x-intercept"])
            {
                case "1":
                    context.Request.Path = "/Diagnostics/Heartbeat";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    context.Request.Path = "/Diagnostics/Deadbeat";
                    break;
            }

            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

To summarize my expectations:

- With no custom header

  - User calls the uri `https://myapplication.com/Diagnostics/Heartbeat`
  - Application routes the request to the `Heartbeat` action of the `Diagnostics` controller
- With the custom header having a value of "2"

  - User calls the uri `https://myapplication.com/Diagnostics/Heartbeat`
  - Application routes the request to the `Deadbeat` action of the `Diagnostics` controller

However, the actual behaviour is that when calling the above uri it is always the `Heartbeat` action that is called regardless of the presence or value of the custom header even though I can see that the value of `context.Request.Path` *has* been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you should add `app.UseRouting();` before the
app.MapControllers, then modifying the context.path could work.

Like below :

```
app.UseMiddleware<ModifyControllerMiddleware>();

app.UseErrorHandler();

app.UseAuthorization();

//add this 
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is my middelware:

```
public class ModifyControllerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ModifyControllerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Request.Headers["x-intercept"])
        {
            case "1":
                context.Request.Path = "/api/mydata";
                break;
            case "2":

                context.Request.Path = "/GetWeatherForecast";
                //context.Request.Path = "/Diagnostics/Deadbeat";
                break;
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: OK, thank you, this solved the issue. But if you were able to link me to whatever resources document this it would be appreciated because I was unable to find anything that indicated that this would be necessary.